VSCode does not loads environment variables when debugging a specific test [golang]
When selecting a specific test to debug on VSCode , the envFile configuration parameter does not loads the configuration file with the specified env vars.
Current debug configuration :
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch File",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/microservice/main.go",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/local/env/.env",
            "showLog":true,
            "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

When accessing via os.Getenv("ENV_VARIABLE_NAME") the debugger marks the read variable as empty .

in the .env file you are setting the variables in format -> ENV_VARIABLE_NAME="dev"  , is that correct?

yes that is the case

In order for VSCode to load the env file all tests must be run , not only the current test . In the debug pane click on "start debugging" and wait for the breakpoint to hit the desired test case to run , do this instead of just running "run test" on the left side of a test .

